# why is piping pgrep output into kill is not working

Tags: command-line

I am playing around with pipes to learn how to use them.
I am trying this command to kill a process by name: `pgrep <some_process> | kill`

but the output I am getting is the usage instruction for kill, like it didn't receive any input.

of course I know there are easier way to accomplish the same task like `pkill` or `killall`, but I want to know why is this not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill` is not reading anything from stdin but expects some command line args and throws an error if it doesn't get them.

Piping only works if the program on the right side of the pipe is actually reading from the pipe. Not all programs do.

Comment: Thank you, I was reading the man page and didn't find anything about how `kill` expect its argument, where can I find this info ? and would you please explain the difference between expecting a command line argument and reading from the STDIN.
Thanks again :)

Comment: `man kill` SYNOPSIS is `kill [options] <pid> [...]`. That means at least one <pid> argument is mandatory and imply `kill` with no argument is doomed.

Answer (score 2):

As Florian explained, `kill` expects command line inputs.

To go around the problem you can use

- `xargs` to build command line arguments for a command, e.g., `pgrep vivaldi | xargs kill` or better yet `pgrep vivaldi | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} 1' | xargs kill`
- shell's substitution:  `kill $(pgrep vivaldi)`
- `killall` which does pretty much the same job as pgrep and kill combined , e.g., `killall vivaldi`
- `pkill` , another utility to kill based on name, e.g., `pkill vivaldi`

Comment: What's the point of the `awk`? There's no reason to strip the newline, the pipe will deal with it. By the way, you could have also simplified it to `awk -ORS=" " '1'`

Comment: @terdon so you're saying it's not necessary to put all the PIDs on the same line ?

Answer (score 0):

For killing a program by its name, if you actually know the process' name, you could just use the command `skill <your process name>`;

Now for pipes, a good way to understand them is playing around with tools like `echo`, `more`, `less`, `tail`, `head`, etc. There are many programs that can actually read from a pipe... one I have always used is `grep`.